# How do I prove that $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = \sqrt{n}$ has solutions for $x$ and $y$ if and only if $n$ is a multiple of a square greater than $1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

(Natural solutions for x and y) Intuitively I know this is correct but I'm not sure on how to proceed in actually proving it. I have tried squaring both sides and while putting $n$ in the form of $ak^2$ which I can't follow up on. I realise that the product $xy$ must be a square in order for this to work but have found no way to implement that into a solution. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Having trouble reading the above. There are real solutions for all x and y if n is twice the sum of their arithmetic and geometric means. Integer solutions for n occur for integer x and y where their product is a perfect square.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed I think you're misreading the question. We are looking for solutions for $x$ and $y$ (given $n$). We're not asking "for which $x$ and $y$ is $n$ an integer" but "for which $n$ can we choose integers $x$ and $y$".

Comment: Well not just $xy$ must be a perfect square but $xn$ and $yn$ as well. If we partition $x=k_xx'^2; y=k_yy'^2;n=k_ny'^2$ where $k_{}$ are square free we get the $k_{}$ are all equal.  Which I think does it.  The only way for $n$ to be square free is for $n=k_n$ and we get $(x' + y')\sqrt{k_n} = \sqrt{k_n}$.   ... I think.... someone might need to proof this.

Comment: FWIW, the equation is equivalent to $x^2 + y^2 - 2xy + n^2 - 2nx - 2ny = 0$.

Comment: When you claim what you've tried, you need to show it in your post.  At the very least, show us, explicitly, what you claim to have tried

Comment: If asking a question for which you want integer solutions, it is important to mention the word "integer" in the question. (The phrase "natural solutions" can mean many other things.)

Comment: If you show your work then the question may get reopened (and I will post an *intuitive* way to prove it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Begin by solving for, say, $y$ in terms of $x$; we get $\sqrt y = \sqrt n - \sqrt x$, or $$y = n+x - 2\sqrt{nx}.$$ If we want positive integer solutions for $x$ and $y$, we have the following requirements to make this work:

1. $x$ must be an integer such that $\sqrt{nx}$ is also an integer.
2. $x>0$ and $y>0$, which is equivalent to checking $0 < x < n$.

It's the $x<n$ here that's the sticking point: we always have the trivial solutions $$\sqrt 0 + \sqrt n = \sqrt n + \sqrt 0 = \sqrt n,$$ but I assume you do not consider $0$ a natural number, and want to rule this out.

So we are asking: for which $n$ is there a natural number $x<n$ such that $nx$ is a perfect square?

If $n = ak^2$ for $k>1$, there is a natural choice for $x$. Conversely, if $n$ is square-free, you want to prove that no such $x$ exists: that the smallest $x>0$ for which $nx$ is a perfect square is $x=n$.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? I am hoping the downvoter answers that question because it affects whether I answer the math question. I have been given a moderator notice about answering PSQs. If the downvote came because this is considered a PSQ, then I should refrain from adding my own answer.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. It is correct  +1

Comment: I do not consider this a PSQ; most of the body of the question is partial progress. (I see now that it was edited in after the question was posted, which may have kickstarted the close votes early on.) I think it is downvoted because a question that's under close votes feels "PSQ-adjacent", but as it happens, I also disagree with the close votes; the question is clear, but some comments came from people who did not read carefully.

Comment: What's PSQ stand for?

Comment: @TurlocTheRed PSQ = Problem Statement Question i.e., a question asked on here with no context nor effort shown

Comment: Surely not the case here:  " I have tried squaring both sides and while putting n in..." and "I realise that the product xy must be a square in order for this to work but have found no way to..." clearly show effort and context.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that if $\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt n$ (all natural) that $xy$ must be a perfect square.

[$\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt n \implies x + 2\sqrt{xy} + y = n \implies$ that $\sqrt {xy}$ is rational and as $xy$ is an integer $xy$ must be a perfect square.]

But by rewriting $\sqrt x =\sqrt n - \sqrt y$ and $\sqrt y = \sqrt n - \sqrt x$ we get by the exact same reasoning $xn$ and $yn$ are also perfect squares.

If we rewrite all as product of a squarefree number and a square so $x = kx'^2, y = jy'^2$ and $n = hn'^2$ where $k,j,h$ are square free we get that  $xy = kjx'^2y'^2; xn=khx'^2n'^2; yn=jhy'^2n'^2$ are all perfect squares.

So $kj, kh, jh$ are all perfect squares depsite $k,j,h$ all being squarefree.  If $p$ is any prime dividing $k$ (and it can only be to a single power) then $p$ must also divide $j$ for $kj$ to be square.  And that is true of any combinations of $j,k,h$.  So $j,k,h$ have the exact same prime factors all to a single power.

So $k=j=h$.

From there the result follows that

$\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt n\implies $

$\sqrt k x' + \sqrt k y' = \sqrt k n'\implies $

$x' + y' = n'$.

And $n' \ge 2$ and $n$ is a product of a non-trivial square.

....

To prove the other direction if $n$ is a product of a nontrivial square (say, $n = km^2$) implies solutions exist:

Just let $a+b$ be any two natural numbers so that $a + b = m \ge 2$ and let $x=ka^2$ and $y=kb^2$.

Answer (score 0):

We apply the difference of squares factorization:

$(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})=x-y$

and so

$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{n}$

$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}=\dfrac{x-y}{\sqrt{n}}=\dfrac{(x-y)\sqrt{n}}{n}$

Taking the half the sum and half the difference between the last two equations renders

$\sqrt{x}=\dfrac{\sqrt{n}(n+x-y)}{2n}=\dfrac{p\sqrt{n}}{q}$

$\sqrt{y}=\dfrac{\sqrt{n}(n+y-x)}{2n}=\dfrac{(q-p)\sqrt{n}}{q}$

where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime natural numbers and, for $x$ and $y$ nonzero, $q$ must be at least $2$. Then $x$ and $y$ must both be rational squares times $n$ with the rational factorvhaving lowest-terms denominatir $q$. These products are then natural numbers only if $n$ is divisible by $q^2\ge2^2$.